# How to store a pointer to an array in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers

in my program I have a class with the following constructor:

```
pp = new Particle*[maxN]
```

and inside one function I have:

```
// create the new particle and fill with data
pp[n] = new Particle;
pp[n]->charge = charge;
pp[n]->px = px;
pp[n]->py = py;
pp[n]->pz = pz;

// store the new particle pointer in the array 
//...
```

The problem is that I don't know how to write the code for the last instruction, i.e.

```
// store the new particle pointer in the array
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Your code has already created the new Particle and saved the pointer to it inside the array (`pp[n] = new Particle;`), it doesn't make sense to ask how to store it there afterwards. Also you should not use pointers, arrays and dynamic memory allocation (`new`) for this. Use `std::vector` if there is no particular reason not to, especially as beginner.

Comment: `pp[n] = new Particle;` <- here, you are already doing this. Also the title of your question and what you're asking differ

Comment: 1) Stop using manual memory management. 2) Use `std::array` or `std::vector`. 3)  Please post a [mcve]. Also, smart pointers are a (very useful/good) thing. Please don't write C++98 code in 2018.

Comment: The person who wrote the comments expected you to create the object first, `Particle* p = new Particle; p->charge = ...`, and then store that pointer, `pp[n] = p;`. Since you deviated from the expectations, you got stuck.

Comment: eukaryota, Jesper Juhl this code is part of an exercise that asks to use those specific things. Thanks anyway for the advice :) @molbdnilo thanks, 
this is the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that I don't know how to write the code for the last instruction, i.e.
>
> ```
> // store the new particle pointer in the array
> ```

You've already done that on the first line:

> ```
> pp[n] = new Particle;
> ```

`new Particle` creates a `Particle` object with dynamic storage, and result of the expression is a pointer to the object. `pp[n] = ...` assigns the pointer at index `n` of the array pointed by `pp`.

PS. It is a bad design to have bare owning pointers within a class like this. To avoid memory leaks and undefined behaviour, it is recommended to use containers instead.